# How to create a Virtualenv on an External Drive on Mac?

Tags: macos, python-2.7, virtualenv

I am on an external HD, and when i do virtualenv my_env, it throws an OS Error

```
OSError: Command /Volumes/Edrive/devel...loud_venv/bin/python setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed --record record failed with error code 1
```

Is it possible to do this on an External Drive

```
virtuaenv venv -- command i used
New python executable in venv/bin/python
Installing Setuptools.............................................................................................done.
Installing Pip.......
  Complete output from command /Volumes/Edrive/devel...venv/bin/python setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed --record record:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages
ImportError: No module named setuptools
----------------------------------------
...Installing Pip...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.10.1', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 821, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 963, in create_environment
    install_sdist('Pip', 'pip-*.tar.gz', py_executable, search_dirs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 932, in install_sdist
    filter_stdout=filter_install_output)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 899, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Volumes/Edrive/devel...venv/bin/python setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed --record record failed with error code 1
```

I do have setuptools intalled is it related to some Path Errors

Comment: Python -2.7.2
virtualenv 1.10.1

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to create a virtualenv on any mounted, writeable volume. Please share the complete traceback you're seeing, and the command you're executing -- that may give enough information that someone can help you fix the underlying problem.

Also tell us the exact Python and Virtualenv versions for good measure.